# What is the meaning of the text on the hunter license?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

We know that these symbols have a meaning. Doing the equivalence, we obtain some words in the Japanese language.

What does it mean in English?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be something like this in Japanese:

> ハンターライセンス
>
> ハンターライセンスカードについて
>
> 本カードは 本人以外使用不可能でず
>
> 紛失視された際 ライセンスが剥奪される
>
> 事はありませんが カードの再発行はどきません

Which would roughly mean

> Hunter License
>
> About the Hunter License Card
>
> This card cannot be used by anyone other than the proprietor
>
> In case of loss, the license is revoked

I have some trouble with the last line but it's something about the card not being reissueable.

Comment: Well, that is not very consistent to the manga. In fact, you can sell your license if you want (thus the new owner can use it). And about the last line, that is right: you can not obtain a second license, but you still will be a Hunter. Thank you.

Comment: According to the wiki "Only the original recipient of the license has access to the privileges of a Hunter, meaning someone who buys or steals a license will not receive any special benefits." the source being Volume 4, chapter 35. I guess buying a Hunter License is more for collection value

Answer (score -1):

This post is old but for thoses who keep searching here is the full signification :

> **Hunter License**
>
> About the Hunter License Card :
>
> Only the original license recipient has access to Hunter privileges
> *(This card can only be used by the person)*
>
> The license is deleted in case of loss
>
> No matter what happens, the card will not be reissued *(Nothing
> happened, but the card is not reissued)*